# Can't install packages in Atom, in app or cmd

Tags: windows, cmd, atom-editor

I'm trying to install linter for atom, however both in the app and in cmd I get:

> INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
>
> \Java\jre7\bin";C:\Program Files 
>   (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\command;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;" was unexpected at this time.

And I honestly don't know what that means, but I've tried searching for an answer and I can't find it. "atom -v" returns the version (1.10.0), "apm -v" returns the above, as well as any apm command. "where apm" returns

C:\Users\JM\AppData\Local\atom\bin\apm

C:\Users\JM\AppData\Local\atom\bin\apm.cmd

Comment: That looks like your Path variable, can you check it for stuff that shouldn't be in there? like the " in \Java\jre7\bin"; looks like a typo.

Comment: Looks like `apm.cmd` breaks on the second (and last) occurrence of the closing parenthesis: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin"`. I've checked by removing both parentheses and just the closing one, it did run both times.

Comment: Raised an issue: https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/12608

Comment: @sompylasar thanks so much.

Comment: @sompylasar I found the edits made in the repo and edited my apm.cmd file, solved the problem! For anyone wondering, line 12 was changed from `if defined apm_git_path set "Path=!apm_git_path!;%PATH%"` to `if defined apm_git_path set "Path=!apm_git_path!;!PATH!"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/12608#issuecomment-245024152
https://github.com/atom/apm/commit/fa84f2693b22630e5125dcea10004300d00cdd75

I found the edits made in the repo and edited my apm.cmd file, solved the problem! For anyone wondering, line 12 was changed from `if defined apm_git_path set "Path=!apm_git_path!;%PATH%"` to `if defined apm_git_path set "Path=!apm_git_path!;!PATH!"`

This should be fixed on its own in future updates.

Answer (score 0):

There is other solution:

- got to folder with packages
- `git clone https://github.com/developer/some_pack.git`
- `cd some_pack`
- `npm install`
- `apm link`
- it works fine